# JavaScript ES6 - How to combine promise methods in Promise.All?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, es6-promise

I have two promise methods, first one is `GetInitialData` which would run only once, also an Int array of 10 id called `ids` and second method `GetStudentName` which would be executed on each student id. Now I would like to combine all 11 methods (method 1 + 10 * method 2) in Promise.All, how could I write the code which would combine the `GetInitialData` along with 10 instances of `GetStudentName` into an array inside Promise.All, something like below?

```
Promise.All([GetInitialData + IDs.map(Id => GetStudentName(Id)]);
```

Comment: It's unclear what `GetInitialData()` and `GetStudentName(Id)` returns, what is `IDs` here? Please add the full details in the main post.

Comment: `Promise.All(GetInitialData(), ...IDs.map(Id => GetStudentName(Id));`? I find it hard to understand what you're actually after, so this is mostly a guess.

Comment: you need `Promise.All([GetInitialData(), ...IDs.map(GetStudentName)]);`

Comment: Yes, I need a way to combine my method 1 and method 2 which is called through IDs.map, into a new array inside Promise.All, something@AZ_ showed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right path:

```js
Promise.all([
  getInitialData,
  // you need to spread this one as it is an array of promises:
  ...ids.map(id => getStudentName(id),
]);
```

**Here is a demo:**
all async functions are replaced with promises that resolves within a random time

```js
const fnPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), Math.round(Math.random() * 1000))
);

let i = 0;

async function getInitialData() {
    await fnPromise();
    return i++;
}

async function getStudentName() {
    await fnPromise();
    return i++;
}

const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

async function init() {
    $("#console").html('Please wait...');
    
    const allResolved = await Promise.all([
        getInitialData(),
        ...ids.map(() => getStudentName()),
    ]);
    
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(allResolved, null, 2))
    $("#console").html(`[${allResolved.join(', ')}]`)
}

init()
```

```css
body {
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
 font-size:2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id='console'></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const getOne = async () => 1;
const getTwo = async () => 2;

(async () => {

    const [one, two] = await Promise.all([getOne(), getTwo()]);

    console.log(one);
    console.log(two);
})().then(undefined);

// 1
// 2
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.